# Printing out iat in pe header

Tags: c++, portable-executable

I am trying to print out the iat beginning with printing dll names of an executable though seem to be getting errors that relate to how I'm traversing the pe header. Can someone please point out where I'm going wrong with my code, I can print section information correctly and it recognizes that iat starts at offset 0 in .idata section which seems correct.:

```
int main()
{
    HANDLE hFile, hFileMap;
    LPBYTE hMap;
    DWORD fileSize;
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS ntHeader;
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER sectionHeader;
    char* filename = "blah";
    hFile = CreateFileA(filename, GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        cout << "Couldn't create file" << endl;
        cin.get();
        return 0;
    }
    fileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, 0);
    hFileMap = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, fileSize, NULL);
    if (!hFileMap){
        cout << "Couldn't map file" << endl;
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        cin.get();
        return 0;
    }
    hMap = (LPBYTE)MapViewOfFile(hFileMap, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, fileSize);
    if (!hMap){
        cout << "Couldn't map view of file" << endl;
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        CloseHandle(hFileMap);
        cin.get();
        return 0;
    }
    dosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)hMap;
    ntHeader = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((DWORD)hMap + dosHeader->e_lfanew);
    if (dosHeader->e_magic != IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE && ntHeader->Signature != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE){
        cout << "Not a valid PE file" << endl;
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        CloseHandle(hFileMap);
        FlushViewOfFile(hMap, 0);
        UnmapViewOfFile(hMap);
        SetFilePointer(hFile, fileSize, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
        SetEndOfFile(hFile);
        CloseHandle(hFileMap);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        cin.get();
        return 0;
    }else{
        cout << "Valid PE" << endl;
    }
    cout << hex << ntHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections << " Sections" << endl<<endl;
    sectionHeader = (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)((DWORD)hMap + dosHeader->e_lfanew + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)+sizeof(IMAGE_FILE_HEADER)+sizeof(IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER));
/*for (int i = 0; i < ntHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections;i++){
    cout << "Name: " << sectionHeader[i].Name << endl;
    cout << "Virtual Address: " << hex << sectionHeader[i].VirtualAddress << endl;
    cout << "Virtual Size: " << hex << sectionHeader[i].Misc.VirtualSize << endl;
    cout << "Pointer To Raw Data: " << hex << sectionHeader[i].PointerToRawData << endl;
    cout << "Raw Size: " << hex << sectionHeader[i].SizeOfRawData << endl;
    cout << "Characteristics: " << hex << sectionHeader[i].Characteristics << endl << endl;
}*/

    DWORD importDirectoryVA = ntHeader->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[1].VirtualAddress; 
    DWORD iatOffsetInSection;
    //sets section which contains iat
    int section = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < ntHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++){
        if (sectionHeader[i].VirtualAddress <= importDirectoryVA &&
        (sectionHeader[i].VirtualAddress + sectionHeader[i].Misc.VirtualSize)>importDirectoryVA){
            iatOffsetInSection = importDirectoryVA - sectionHeader[i].VirtualAddress;
            iatOffsetInSection += sectionHeader[i].PointerToRawData;
            section = i;
        }
    }

    cout << "IAT was found at offset " << hex<< iatOffsetInSection << " in section " << sectionHeader[section].Name << endl;
    if (section == -1){
        cout << "IAT not found in sections" << endl;
    }else{
        cout << "IAT found" << endl;
        PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR firstDll = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)((DWORD)ntHeader->OptionalHeader.ImageBase + sectionHeader[section].VirtualAddress + iatOffsetInSection);
        cout << (DWORD)firstDll << endl;
        int i = 0;
        cout << firstDll[0].Name << endl;
        while(firstDll[i].Name != 0){
            cout << firstDll[i].Name << ":" << endl;
            i++;
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    CloseHandle(hFileMap);
    FlushViewOfFile(hMap, 0);
    UnmapViewOfFile(hMap);
    SetFilePointer(hFile, fileSize, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
    SetEndOfFile(hFile);
    CloseHandle(hFileMap);
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting exactly? Post it

Comment: I get the error AccessViolation error on the line beginning at firstDll[0].Name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First notice that you're using truncation to DWORDs for 64-bit addresses, your code will only work as 32-bit code

```
ntHeader = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((DWORD)hMap + dosHeader->e_lfanew); // DWORD isn't 
                                                                   // enough for 64-bit 
                                                                   // addresses
```

that said, this line is wrong:

```
PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR firstDll = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)((DWORD)ntHeader->OptionalHeader.ImageBase + sectionHeader[section].VirtualAddress + iatOffsetInSection);
```

you calculated the iatOffsetInSection as an offset but you shouldn't add it to the imagebase but rather:

```
PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR firstDll = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)((DWORD_PTR)hMap + iatOffsetInSection);
```

finally printing tne name of the DLLs is wrong because it's a RVA. I fixed some parts of your code:

```
    HANDLE hFile, hFileMap;
    LPBYTE hMap;
    DWORD fileSize;
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS ntHeader;
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER sectionHeader;
    char* filename = "whatever";
    hFile = CreateFileA(filename, GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        cout << "Couldn't create file" << endl;
        cin.get();
        return 0;
    }
    fileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, 0);
    hFileMap = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, fileSize, NULL);
    if (!hFileMap){
        cout << "Couldn't map file" << endl;
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        cin.get();
        return 0;
    }
    hMap = (LPBYTE)MapViewOfFile(hFileMap, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, fileSize);
    if (!hMap){
        cout << "Couldn't map view of file" << endl;
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        CloseHandle(hFileMap);
        cin.get();
        return 0;
    }
    dosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)hMap;
    ntHeader = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((BYTE*)hMap + dosHeader->e_lfanew);
    if (dosHeader->e_magic != IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE && ntHeader->Signature != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE){
        cout << "Not a valid PE file" << endl;
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        CloseHandle(hFileMap);
        FlushViewOfFile(hMap, 0);
        UnmapViewOfFile(hMap);
        SetFilePointer(hFile, fileSize, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
        SetEndOfFile(hFile);
        CloseHandle(hFileMap);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        cin.get();
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Valid PE" << endl;
    }
    cout << hex << ntHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections << " Sections" << endl << endl;
    sectionHeader = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(ntHeader);
    /*for (int i = 0; i < ntHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections;i++){
    cout << "Name: " << sectionHeader[i].Name << endl;
    cout << "Virtual Address: " << hex << sectionHeader[i].VirtualAddress << endl;
    cout << "Virtual Size: " << hex << sectionHeader[i].Misc.VirtualSize << endl;
    cout << "Pointer To Raw Data: " << hex << sectionHeader[i].PointerToRawData << endl;
    cout << "Raw Size: " << hex << sectionHeader[i].SizeOfRawData << endl;
    cout << "Characteristics: " << hex << sectionHeader[i].Characteristics << endl << endl;
    }*/

    DWORD iatVA = -1;
    if (ntHeader->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].Size != 0)
        iatVA = ntHeader->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress;

    if (iatVA == -1){
        cout << "Import Directory not found" << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Import Directory was found at RVA " << hex << iatVA << endl;
        DWORD offset = Rva2Offset(iatVA, sectionHeader, ntHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections); // 00010200
        PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR firstDll = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)((DWORD_PTR)hMap + offset);
        DWORD nameOffset = Rva2Offset(firstDll->Name, sectionHeader, ntHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections);
        cout << (char*)(hMap + nameOffset) << endl;
        // Other DLL names..
        while ( (++firstDll)->Name != NULL) {
            nameOffset = Rva2Offset(firstDll->Name, sectionHeader, ntHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections);
            cout << (char*)(hMap + nameOffset) << endl;
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(hFileMap);
    CloseHandle(hFile);
```

Notice that the above will still need some cleaning and there are some casts to revise. It's a *start from here and work your way off*.

Comment: I know VirtualAddress is an RVA which is why I added ImageBase `PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR firstDll = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)((DWORD)ntHeader->OptionalHeader.ImageBase + sectionHeader[section].VirtualAddress + iatOffsetInSection)`

Comment: Based on this I get the result that first PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR is at 00403000 which matches the import table Virtual Address in Data Directory. I know this is the beginning of the array of PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTORS but I can't seem to loop through array and print details from each element of array.

Comment: I tried two different methods to access fields of first PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR both gave the same acces violation error [link](http://pastebin.com/ysymG1eV)

Comment: @user28130 Updated my answer, take a look at the code

Comment: Thanks I managed to print dlls and all function from dlls. I still seem to keep getting confused/forgetful about various offsets.